# response header is null in $httpProvider.interceptors responseError in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, response, angular-http-interceptors, response-headers

I add `errorHandlerInterceptor` to handle errors as you seen below:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('rasool')
        .config(httpConfig);

    function httpConfig($httpProvider) {

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('errorHandlerInterceptor');
    }
})();
```

and in the `errorHandlerInterceptor` i want to get a specific header from response headers like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('rasool')
        .factory('errorHandlerInterceptor', errorHandlerInterceptor);

    function errorHandlerInterceptor ($q, toaster, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        var service = {
            responseError: responseError
        };

        return service;

        function responseError (response) {

            var errorHeader = response.headers('X-app-alert');

            if(errorHeader) {
                // do something
            }

            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    }
})();
```

The problem is that the `errorHeader` is null, but when i check the response headers with Chrome DevTools, this header exists and have a value as you can see in the below screenshot:

[image]

**UPDATE**

All of these part are running correctly in the website, but i created a copy of html, js and css files to create an ionic1 application, but when i run `ionic serve` command to test the application, i have this problem.

Comment: Are you sure that by the time you are trying to access the response header the promise is already resolved?

Comment: The non-standard header needs to be listed with [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers).

Comment: @georgeawg, as you seen above in the screenshot, `X-app-alert` already exists in the response headers, but angular does not get this header

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call it like this:

```
var errorHeader = response.headers();
```

and after errorHeader should be an object that have the data you need.